# Current location button is not moving in google map API android

Tags: android, google-maps

I added this code in my application :

```
theMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
            Log.e("bounds ", bounds.southwest.toString()+" "+bounds.northeast.toString());
            theMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100));
        }
    });
```

after that , the move to current button does not work.
Thank you

Comment: Did you tried `getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)`? If you have latest Google Play service version you can use this asynchronous method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Uninstall and build again it work OK.
Sorry for this question.